# MacBook Pro WiFi keeps shutting down for no apparent reason

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro

I've got quite a problem with my Macbook Pro (late 2010, running OS X Lion 10.7.3).
Since a few days ago, my wifi frequently keeps shutting down. It starts by the network not being functional and then when I switch AirPort off/on, it does not want to switch on. It keeps being switched off. Only a restart fixes the problem. But it keeps coming back.

I already reset the SMC and P-RAM, nothing helps.

Is anybody familiar with this problem and might be able to help me out? I would appreciate it.

Best regards!

Here's what I could discover in Console that might have something to do with it:

```
3/7/12 6:15:24.000 PM kernel: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
3/7/12 6:15:25.657 PM UserEventAgent: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptivePublishState:1211 en1 - PreProbe
3/7/12 6:15:25.664 PM configd: network configuration changed.
3/7/12 6:15:25.667 PM applepushserviced: <APSCourier: 0x7fb0e9d0c3f0>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x102d294c0>: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected
3/7/12 6:15:25.682 PM applepushserviced: <APSCourier: 0x7fb0e9d0c3f0>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x102d294c0>: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)
3/7/12 6:15:25.685 PM applepushserviced: <APSCourier: 0x7fb0e9d0c3f0>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x102d294c0>: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)
3/7/12 6:15:28.192 PM applepushserviced: <APSCourier: 0x7fb0e9d0c3f0>: Stream error occurred for <APSTCPStream: 0x7fb0e9e17270>: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)
3/7/12 6:15:31.000 PM kernel: VendorID check timed out ! Issuing secondary bus reset 
3/7/12 6:15:32.000 PM kernel: WLAN adapter not yet powered or is not in the system (stateNumber = 1)!
3/7/12 6:15:32.000 PM kernel: wl: syncPowerState called when card is down.
3/7/12 6:15:32.000 PM kernel: WLAN adapter not yet powered or is not in the system (stateNumber = 2)!
3/7/12 6:15:32.000 PM kernel: wl: enable called when card is down.
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you know how to fix this yet?

Comment: No. I tried several other things (deleting all networks and restart, deleting and put again the wifi adapter from the list, remove the Ethernet adapter from the list, disable Bluetooth). I start thinking that it's either a really nasty firmware bug or it's a hardware issue. I will open my notebook and check the connections to the wifi module. Stay tuned.

Comment: I'd also love to know where you managed to get with this, as I'm experiencing the problem consistently. It does feel more like a hardware issue though, as I've had it in both 10.6 and 10.7.

Comment: I'm also having this same exact issue. I have a mid-2010 MBP running 10.7.3, and the problems began about three weeks ago. The hard drive, airport card and logic board have all recently been replaced.

Comment: I've been having this too. I wrote up a script to deal with it - https://gist.github.com/2986161.
It doesn't solve the problem, but it at least recovers from it quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the exact same problem before with my Mid-2010 MacBook Pro. I took it into the Apple support people on campus and, after running quite a few tests, they found out that the cable connecting the AirPort card to the motherboard had gone bad. It sounds like this is the same thing that you're experiencing, so your best bet is to see about getting that cable replaced.

Comment: I opened my Macbook and checked the connection on the Airport Chip. They seemed to be okay. Anyhow, I disconnected them, cleaned it with compressed air and reconnected them. (Made sure they were connected really good). It seems to be working now. So after all it was a hardware problem.